# Limit and sort inline Map/Reduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

As far as I know, I can't specify a complex sort function in Mongo so I have to use a map/reduce query which feels a bit useless since I don't even use the reduce portion. This is fine but the collection it returns is too large, I need to sort and limit it (paginate).  Is it possible to do that with an inline call? I can't store the resulting collection and then query it because the collection is unique to each user and constantly changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally `sort` in mongodb mapreduce applied before the map, literally they are applied to the input data not the output.

From mongodb docs

```
   [, sort : <sorts the input objects using this key. Useful for optimization, like sorting by the emit key for fewer reduces>]
   [, limit : <number of objects to return from collection>]
```

So if you want to sort & limit the map reduce output, you must store the result in temp collection. I dont think its possible to apply the sort & limit to the `inline` mapreduce output since it runs on RAM.

**EDIT:**

There is a open issue ([Add support for sorting and limiting inline map/reduce](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3973)) in mongodb Jira regarding  this. Have a look.